# Members Rank only areas

Tags: php, mysql, membership

In my site I have a Staff lounge, But it seems that everyone can see it, whether your a member or now.

Header.inc.php:

```
$userinfo = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$username'"));
$rank = $userinfo[rank];
$rank1 = $userinfo[rank1];
$rank2 = $userinfo[rank2];
$rank3 = $userinfo[rank3];
$rank4 = $userinfo[rank4];



if (!$checkrank) { $checkrank = 0; }
if (!$rank) { $rank = 0; }
if (!$rank == ' ') { $rank = 0; }
if ($rank < $checkrank)
{

     header("Location: $baseurl/index.php?error=You+can+not+view+this+page.");
}

if ($rank >= 30)
{

    $admin = "<a href=\"$baseurl/staff/admin.php\">Admin</a>";
}
```

Ranks are 5-30 The higher the rank the more of the staff lounge members can see, However No matter what peoples ranks are everyone can see the page (BUT THE ADMIN AREA, Thats the only thing no one can see other than RANK 30 people)

At the top of each page I have (banners.php):

```
   $checkrank = 5;

    if ($rank <= 0)
    {
                header("Location: $baseurl/index.php?article=$article&error=Only+SketchedNeo+staff+can+see+this.");

    }

include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/staff/header.inc.php');
```

A friend and I sat here for hours last night, Changing the $checkrank to 20 and the if $rank 18 and then making her rank to 15 on the database, but she would still see all pages.

My database structure is:

```
id int(11) 
username varchar(200) latin1_swedish_ci 
password varchar(216) latin1_swedish_ci 
security varchar(200) latin1_swedish_ci 
email varchar(216) latin1_swedish_ci 
ip varchar(200) latin1_swedish_ci 
rank varchar(216) latin1_swedish_ci 
name varchar(30) latin1_swedish_ci 
age varchar(40) latin1_swedish_ci 
gender varchar(40) latin1_swedish_ci 
location varchar(40) latin1_swedish_ci 
helpfaerie int(11) 
profile text latin1_swedish_ci 
about text latin1_swedish_ci 
tasks text latin1_swedish_ci 
joined varchar(216) latin1_swedish_ci 
laston int(200) 
icedmutereason text latin1_swedish_ci 
icedmutedetails text latin1_swedish_ci 
icedmuteby varchar(200) latin1_swedish_ci 
icedmutedate int(200) 
posts int(11) 
signature varchar(216) latin1_swedish_ci 
avatar varchar(216) latin1_swedish_ci 
neohtml text latin1_swedish_ci 
siggy text latin1_swedish_ci 
verify int(11) 
changedpass int(1)
```

How can I make it so only members with a minimum rank see pages?
I need it to be for example members with rank 17+ can see this page, Therefore members with ranks 16 and Lower are redirected back to the home page.

---

I found a tutorial for ACL (access control list)

Comment: $rank <= 0 this? I did, I made it 18 and the checkrank 20 last night, still let people see it who were rank 15

Comment: `if (!$rank = ' ')`? Don't you mean `if ($rank != ' ')`?

Comment: Ive Accepted the answers from previous questions now.

Comment: Marc B, I have now put if ($rank != ' ') { $rank = 0; } (on the header.inc.php), Though Now If I put include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/staff/header.inc.php'); Above the $checkrank = 5;

if ($rank <= 0)
{
         header("Location: $baseurl/index.php?article=$article&error=Only+SketchedNeo+staff+can+see+this.");

} code I get  headers already sent by error (though I can see the page) If I put include ($_SER below the code, then It directs me either way even if I am high enough rank to see the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prevent any page output after sending redirect headers.

```
header("Location: $baseurl/index.php");
die();
```

If you don't stop the script from executing, then the redirect will never happen.

Comment: Its now redirecting everyone.

Comment: Currently its :include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/staff/header.inc.php');


$checkrank = 15;

if ($rank <= 14)
{
         header("Location: $baseurl/index.php?article=$article&error=Only+SketchedNeo+staff+can+see+this.");
die();
}... My rank is 30 so i should see the page, But I get a blank page. with Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /hermes/waloraweb085/b2027/moo.lutarinet/staff/header.inc.php:2) in /hermes/waloraweb085/b2027/moo.lutarinet/staff/add_banner.php on line 11

Comment: By blank page I mean, the layout etc all shows up, but the page infomation (table to add new banners to the site) is not showing.

Comment: Staff header.inc.php has: if (!$checkrank) { $checkrank = 0; }
if (!$rank) { $rank = 0; }
if ($rank != ' ') { $rank = 0; }
if ($rank < $checkrank)
{

  header("Location: $baseurl/index.php?error=You+can+not+view+this+page.");
}

Comment: The error explains itself. Your header.inc.php is generating output. You cannot redirect after output has been generated. You need to put your redirect code BEFORE output starts.

Comment: I put the header include below it, and get I get directed to the index page, Even though Im high enough rank to see the page.

Comment: The redirection is coming from the banner.php page not the header page, If this helps you explaining things to me.

Comment: I'm not your personal debugger. You clearly don't understand the logic of your own code. I fixed your header issue, the rest is up to you.