# Page can only be seen by members with a certain rank

Tags: php, redirect, member

In my members database I have a section called rank.

Basically what im trying to do is make certain pages viewable to members with a rank higher than 12 for example, and if the rank is lower than 12 then they are redirected back to the home page. (obviously their will be lots of different pages for rank 5+ members, Rank 7+ members, rank 20+ members etc)

Can anyone help me with a tutorial or something please?

I did ask for help earlier with my current code, but I dont think that code is ever going to work, Ive been changing it and playing with it for a week now and can not possibly see any other ways to get it to work [Members Rank only area's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11450594/members-rank-only-areas/11450704#comment15112749_11450704)

I am still learning php, So ideally a nice easy explaining tutorial would be nice.

Database:

```
id int(11) 
username varchar(200) latin1_swedish_ci 
password varchar(216) latin1_swedish_ci 
security varchar(200) latin1_swedish_ci 
email varchar(216) latin1_swedish_ci 
ip varchar(200) latin1_swedish_ci 
rank varchar(216) latin1_swedish_ci 
name varchar(30) latin1_swedish_ci 
age varchar(40) latin1_swedish_ci 
gender varchar(40) latin1_swedish_ci 
location varchar(40) latin1_swedish_ci 
helpfaerie int(11) 
profile text latin1_swedish_ci 
about text latin1_swedish_ci 
tasks text latin1_swedish_ci 
joined varchar(216) latin1_swedish_ci 
laston int(200) 
icedmutereason text latin1_swedish_ci 
icedmutedetails text latin1_swedish_ci 
icedmuteby varchar(200) latin1_swedish_ci 
icedmutedate int(200) 
posts int(11) 
signature varchar(216) latin1_swedish_ci 
avatar varchar(216) latin1_swedish_ci 
neohtml text latin1_swedish_ci 
siggy text latin1_swedish_ci 
verify int(11) 
changedpass int(1)
```

Header.inc.php

```
<?php 

include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/dblink.php'); 
include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/addon.php'); 

$geterror= $_GET['error'];

$error= stripplus($geterror);

$extra = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM extra WHERE id='1'"));


$cp = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '$username'"));



$weather = $extra[weather];
$wurl = $extra[wurl];
$games = $extra[games];
$xword = $extra[xword];
$xword2 = $extra[xword2];
$xworddate = date("M j Y",$extra[xworddate]); 
$userinfo = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$username'"));
$rank = $userinfo[rank];




if (!$checkrank) { $checkrank = 0; }
if (!$rank) { $rank = 0; }
if (!$rank == ' ') { $rank = 0; }
if ($rank < $checkrank)
{

     header("Location: $baseurl/index.php?error=You+can+not+view+this+page.");
}




if ($rank >= 30)
{

    $admin = "<a href=\"$baseurl/staff/admin.php\">Admin</a>";
}


if ($username)
{

mysql_query("UPDATE members SET laston = $timestamp+120 WHERE username='$username'");

mysql_query("UPDATE members SET ip = '$ip' WHERE username='$username'");

    $login = "Welcome $username :) <a href=\"$baseurl/logout.php\" >Logout</a>";

$helpfaerie = "<a href=\"$baseurl/helpfaerie.php\" >Help Faerie</a>";

}

else
{
$login = "<form name=\"login\" action=\"$baseurl/login.pro.php\" method=\"post\"  > <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"act\" value=\"doLogin\" color=\"#000000\" valign=\"middle\" >&nbsp;Username: <input type=\"text\" name=\"username\" color=\"#000000\"  style=\"width:100px; height:20px;font-size:10px;\">
Password: <input type=\"password\" name=\"password\"  style=\"width:100px; height:20px;font-size:10px;\"> <input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Login\" style=\"width:42px; height:20px;font-size:10px;\"></form>";


}


ECHO <<<END
```

and then the font.php

```
<?php
$pagetitle = "Add Font";





session_start();

// Rank Limit
       $limit = 10;

        // Using a session 
    $rank = $_SESSION['rank'];

       // Using a cookie
       $rank = $_COOKIE['rank'];

    if ($rank < $limit) {
        header("$baseurl/index.php?error=You+can+not+view+this+page.");
        exit();
        die();
    }


include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/staff/header.inc.php');


ECHO <<<END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is an ACL (access control list) probably combined with authentication. An ACL will allow you to specify which resources a user with specific credentials has access to.

I have located a few tutorials, but this is not for the faint of heart.

- http://phpmaster.com/role-based-access-control-in-php/
- http://blog.davidjclarke.co.uk/database-driven-zend-acl-tutorial-part-one.html
- http://www.developer.com/lang/php/creating-a-custom-acl-in-php.html

and maybe you could use a class from phpclasses to get you started:

[PHPClasses ACL search result](http://www.phpclasses.org/search.html?words=acl&x=0&y=0&go_search=1)

Also as far as I know all of the popular frameworks have ACL and Authentication resources. (Zend Framework, Symfony, CakePHP).

Good luck!

Comment: @halfer, thanks for making it pretty. It's been a long night.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a rank field in your database you'll have to retrieve it with a query:

```
$user = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT rank FROM members WHERE username='$username'"));
```

after that you can check it and then you have to create a if/switch to manage the various rank and the logic behind it:

```
if(!is_array($user) || $user['rank'] < 12){
     header('Location: homepage');
} else {
 //manage page that only ranked user can have

}
```

bare in mind this is an easy and also "bad" solution becouse it will do a query every page you will access and for each user but it will give you the idea, you could work for a bit more complex version by using a login page that will store in session the rank and just retrieve it in each page to decide if the user can view it or not:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_rank'] || $_SESSION['user_rank']<12)
    header('Location : defaultpage.php');
```

Comment: Where you've put {
 //manage page that only ranked user can have

} Do I just leave that? and then continue to the ECHO <<<END Page content css and html would be here

Comment: you should avoid putting content outside the else branch to avoid output that would interfere with the header() function. all the include/html should be inside it. Example: if ($rank < $limit) {
        header("$baseurl/index.php?error=You+can+not+view+this+page.");
        exit();
        die();
    } else {  echo HTML}